# Using Apex to determine Connected App

Tags: apex, managed-package, metadata-api, connected-apps

I want to share an Apex class with two **Connected Apps** that will be housed in different Managed Packages: ProdApp and TestApp.

Is there a way to programmatically determine which of the two Connected Apps the code is being used by?

Found this example but it specifically says it won't work in a Managed Package:

```
public static void retrieveConnectedApp() {
  // This only seems to work for Connected App's created in the org, not those packaged, see Workbench only created ones get listed
  MetadataService.MetadataPort service = new MetadataService.MetadataPort();
  service.SessionHeader = new MetadataService.SessionHeader_element();
  service.SessionHeader.sessionId = UserInfo.getSessionId();
  MetadataService.ConnectedApp connectedApp =
                (MetadataService.ConnectedApp)service.readMetadata('ConnectedApp', new String[] {'Test' }).getRecords()[0];
  System.Debug('connectedApp = ' + connectedApp);        
}
```

Comment: Well, you can use a simple method to determine if its a sandbox or prod based on that you can assume its prod app or test app. This comes with additional assumption that you'd be always using prodapp class for prod and test app for test

Comment: Unfortunately, the TestApp is used both in Sandboxes and Developer Edition tenants. ProdApp is never used in a Sandbox but it could be in a Developer Edition tenant.